# CatalogSearch - exclude child product names from fulltext

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, fulltext

I've been playing with the catalogsearch for a while, and I'm almost done, but there is one odd thing happening to me. The only "*usable in search*" attributes are `name`, `child_skus` and `synonyme`. In `child_skus`, I'm storing the skus of the associated products of my grouped products, as I'm working with grouped products only on the frontend. `synonyme` contains a list of coma-separated words which related to the said product.

What I'm using for the fulltext search is the following code :

```
$query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($searchText)->prepare();
$fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
            Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'), 
            $searchText, 
            $query
        );
$products->getSelect()->joinInner(
            array('search_result' => $products->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
            $products->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
                $query->getId()
            ),
            array('relevance' => 'relevance')
        );
$products->getSelect()->order('relevance DESC');
```

All works fine for now, **except** that somehow, it also indexes the associated product's name in the fulltext table, which ends up jamming my search because it yields biased results.

Does anyone have any idea on how to change that behaviour, or control it through admin?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a very good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the method `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::_rebuildStoreIndex`. That's the one that actually rebuilds the fultext search index.
Somewhere inside it you will find this:

```
$productChildren = $this->_getProductChildIds($productData['entity_id'], $productData['type_id']);
$productRelations[$productData['entity_id']] = $productChildren;
```

and later

```
if ($productChildren = $productRelations[$productData['entity_id']]) {
   foreach ($productChildren as $productChildId) {
       if (isset($productAttributes[$productChildId])) {
           $productIndex[$productChildId] = $productAttributes[$productChildId];
       }
   }
}
```

This means that for configurable, grouped and bundle products the child product attributes are indexed also.
You can rewrite the model and remove this parts, or leave it like it is and simply rewrite the method `_getProductChildIds` in the same class and make it return `null` so it will be like there are no child products for any other product.
this way the child products will not be indexed in the parent product data.

Comment: looks brilliant, let me check that ;)

Comment: @JulienLachal. I forgot to mention that I didn't test that. Just took my shovel and dug up the code. But it seams like the way to go.

Comment: it works, but I'm having a hard time overriding the file for some reason, it'll do for now but I'll have to clean this :p thanks for your help.

Comment: @Marius how to do this in magento2.3.2

Comment: I do not know.probably inthe same way

Answer (score 1):

You can already set the synonyms in the back-office with "search term" in the catalog menu. To do that the search term as to have been already used in front-office and then you can redirect to the product, category or cms page you like.
For products, you can set visibility accordingly to what you want to display in search results so you don't really need to bother about the child_skus.

I would suggest you to install elasticsearch or solr with an appropriate module to really improve search results. Moreover, you can really manage better with fuzzy queries, wild cards and so on.

Comment: synonyme isn't quite like search terms, and it's easier to manage for my clients than having to set each individual search terms. Visibility didn't quite make it in terms of associated product sku's, so I had to find another trick. I really don't want to bother with another module, my site already has plenty.