# Exclude child products from search in magento 2.3.2

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.3.2

I am trying to exclude child products from search. Say I have a bundle product B1 with 'xyz' name and it has a child with name 'abc'. Now searching for 'abc' in frontend also gives the product B1 in search results.

What I need is If I search 'abc' then I should not get product B1 in the search results.
I have tried following solutions but they are related to magento 1

[CatalogSearch - exclude child product names from fulltext](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37032/catalogsearch-exclude-child-product-names-from-fulltext)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907666/magento-search-result-excluding-tthe-child-products

In magento2.3.2 I did not find Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::_rebuildStoreIndex function.
ofcourse I looked for this inside vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext.php

But I found a similar function that I felt is doing the reindexing part.function is next() It is located in

\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\IndexIterator.php

I tried commenting the following line as suggested in above solutions

```
// $productChildren = $this->productRelations[$productData['entity_id']];
    // if ($productChildren) {
        // foreach ($productChildren as $productChildId) {
            // if (isset($this->productAttributes[$productChildId])) {
                // $productChildAttr = $this->productAttributes[$productChildId];
                // if (!isset($productChildAttr[$this->status->getId()])
                    // || !in_array($productChildAttr[$this->status->getId()], $this->statusIds)
                // ) {
                    // continue;
                // }

                // $hasChildren = true;
                // $productIndex[$productChildId] = $productChildAttr;
            // }
        // }
    // }
```

cleaned cache, reindexed, but still getting results based on child products. Any suggestion how I can achieve this.